# How to implement interstitial Ads using AdMob in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, admob

I'm implementing the interstitial Ads using the AdMob stuff but it is not displaying.

This is my class where I want to implement interstitial ads.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class SearchNew: UIViewController{

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")

        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
        self.interstitial.loadRequest(request)

        self.showAd()
    }

    func showAd() {
        if self.interstitial.isReady {
            self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even I've referred this site i.e https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial  but not getting interstitial ads on my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add delegate function (GADInterstitialDelegate) for your class.

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,  GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var mInterstitial: GADInterstitial!
    var gViewController: UIViewController?
```

Call loadRequest, it fires interstitialDidReceiveAd when ads ready to show

```
    func showAdmobInterstitial()
    {
            self.mInterstitial = GADInterstitial.init(adUnitID:kGoogleFullScreenAppUnitID )

            mInterstitial.delegate = self
            let Request  = GADRequest()
            Request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
            mInterstitial.loadRequest(Request)
    }

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!)
    {
        ad.presentFromRootViewController(self.gViewController)
    }
```

Call showAdmobInterstitial from any viewController

```
            let App = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            App.gViewController = self;
            App.showAdmobInterstitial()
```

Comment: Thanks...I've got it and now interstitial ads are displaying on my app. Now I got the concept of this.

Answer (score 0):

```
In this way I did this admob Interstitial ads task

import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

//-------Interstitial adds--------
Step 1: You need to add this stuff in side your AppDelegate.swift file

@UIApplicationMain
Delegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var gViewController: UIViewController?

    var window: UIWindow?


 func showAdmobInterstitial()
    {
        let kGoogleFullScreenAppUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910";
        self.mInterstitial = GADInterstitial.init(adUnitID:kGoogleFullScreenAppUnitID )

        mInterstitial.delegate = self
        let Request  = GADRequest()
        Request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
        mInterstitial.loadRequest(Request)
    }

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!)
    {
        ad.presentFromRootViewController(self.gViewController)
    }
//-------------------------
```

Step 2:  Now where ever or in any veiwController you want to show interstitial ads then add this stuff within that file.

```
let App = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            App.gViewController = self;
            App.showAdmobInterstitial()

By this way we can call now interstitial ads easily.
```